# Cannot use a select or any of the database statements in a multi-query prepare

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, exception, informix

Q:

I get the following exception when i try to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO days  (depcode,studycode,batchnum) values (3,3,4);SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' )
FROM systables
WHERE tabid = 1;
```

Through `ExecuteScalar()` .

> ERROR:-555  MEssage: [Informix .NET provider][Informix]Cannot use a
>   select or any of the database statements in a multi-query prepare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The statement text that is presented with this PREPARE statement has
>   multiple statements divided by semicolons, and one is a SELECT,
>   DATABASE, CREATE DATABASE, or CLOSE DATABASE statement. These
>   statements must always be prepared as one-statement texts. Check the
>   statement text string, and make sure that you intended multiple
>   statements. If you did, revise the program to execute these four
>   statement types alone.

Means, try to do the insert and the select in two separate query's.

Comment: hmmm, i wanna then in the same statement.

Comment: Why do you want them in the same statement?

Comment: because i will insert large number of records (without transation) and i will store all the returned ids from the previous query in a list or array . so if any failure has happened , i will use this list to delete all the inserted records.

Comment: First i don´t know why you will do s.th. like this without transactions. and second: why isn´t that possible by using two statements ?

Comment: No transaction because the number of records is huge and the number of users will be many. so i don't want lock on this table, in addition to the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6483363/418343..no two statements because i wanna to be executed at the same time.